# Jsoup bug? Jsoup.parse get stuck

Tags: jsoup

I try parsing the following URL: http://www.cisg.law.pace.edu/cisg/biblio/full-biblio.html

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.cisg.law.pace.edu/cisg/biblio/full-biblio.html");
int timeout = 20 * 1000;
System.out.println("Start parsing...");
Jsoup.parse(url, timeout);
System.out.println("Done");
```

I run it and never get the "Done" message.
The strange thing is that this HTML is only 3MB, so I can't see a reason why it takes so long.

Comment: For those like me who ran into the hang problem : upgrade Jsoup to 1.12.1-SHAPSHOT resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug. I have tried what you said using the jsoup 1.6.3 release and the execution was getting stuck at `Document doc = DataUtil.parseByteData(byteData, charset, url.toExternalForm(), req.parser());` of `org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection`.

You can validate whether connection is being made using the following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class JSoupTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.cisg.law.pace.edu/cisg/biblio/full-biblio.html");
        //int timeout = 20 * 1000;
        System.out.println("Start parsing...");
        //Jsoup.parse(url, timeout);

        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String line = null;
        while(true)
        {
            line = reader.readLine();
            if(line == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```